# listen to UDP and TCP at same time on server using C++

Tags: multithreading, sockets, tcp, udp, pthreads

I am trying to code a socket and client programs, such that the server should listen to both connections at same time.

For example when I start the server, it will listen to UDP port as well as TCP port and whenever a UDP client sends message, it must process it and when TCP client sends message it must process it.

I tried using pthreads and not able to achieve what I want.

Here are the details in C++ Code

Following function will be called by the respective pthreads

```
void *TCP(void *ptr)
{
    char tcp[MAXDATASIZE];
    cout << "\nEnter TCP port number\n";
    cin >> tcp;
    Server tcpServer(tcp,1);
    tcpServer.testbind(1);
    pthread_exit(NULL);

}

void *UDP(void *ptr)
{
    char udp[MAXDATASIZE];
    cout << "\nEnter UDP port number\n";
    cin >> udp;
    Server udpServer(udp,2);
    udpServer.testDNS(2);
    pthread_exit(NULL);

}
```

Main Program

```
int main(int c, char *argv[])
{
  char tcp[MAX],udp[MAX];
  int choice,choice1;
  void *i;
  pthread_t tcpThread,udpThread;
  int tcpThreadCheck,udpThreadCheck;
  pthread_attr_t attr;
  pthread_attr_init(&attr);
  pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
  choice1 = pthread_create(&tcpThread,NULL,testTCP,i);
  choice = pthread_create(&udpThread,NULL,testUDP,i);
  if(choice <0) cout <<" Main tcp thread failed"<<endl;
  if(choice1 <0) cout <<" Main udp thread failed"<<endl;

  pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Whenever I try to run this server program, I get "Enter TCP Port number " and "Enter UDP port number" simulatenosly or in hay-way manner. I want bot the tcpServer and udpServer to run independently and process the incoming data from respective clients.

Can anyone please help me here, how to achieve this. Any examples?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start two threads, and they execute simultaneously. Of course, they print their stuff simulatenously, they are also going to read from std::cin simultaneously with scenic effects. I suggest you get your ports from user BEFORE you start the threads, and than provide the already known port to the threads.

You code has other problems as well - you should not pthread_exit from main(), and you do not need pthread_attr in your case - you can simply provide NULL, default values are exactly what you are supplying.

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot . Your suggestion actually helped a lot